# Combine two lists of data in PHP

Tags: php

So I have several lists of data.
I'd like to have a webpage where I can upload several lists (easy) and have these processed by PHP in order to make several combinations.

I think the easiest way of explaining this is showing what I have and what I want. Therefore, I have several lists as input:

**list 1**
Item1.1
Item1.2
Item1.3

**List 2**
Item2.1
Item2.2
Item2.3

And so on.

The desired output would be:

Item1.1 - Item2.1
Item1.1 - Item2.2
Item1.1 - Item2.3
Item1.2 - Item2.1
Item1.2 - Item2.2
Item1.2 - Item2.3
...

A combination of two lists would be easy, however, In case of three lists it will already become more difficult. The desired outcome would be:

Item1.1 - Item2.1 - Item3.1
Item1.1 - Item2.1 - Item3.2
Item1.1 - Item2.1 - Item3.3
Item1.1 - Item2.2 - Item3.1
Item1.1 - Item2.2 - Item3.2
Item1.1 - Item2.2 - Item3.3
...
Item1.2 - Item2.1 - Item3.1
Item1.2 - Item2.1 - Item3.2
Item1.2 - Item2.1 - Item3.3
Item1.2 - Item2.2 - Item3.1
...

I've made an HTML form with the code below, giving the possibilities to end an undefined amount of lists:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addinput( ) {
            var inp;
            inp = document.createElement("textarea");
            inp.name = "values[]";
            var element = document.getElementById("form");
            element.insertBefore(inp, null);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="addinput()">Voeg extra kolom toe</button> | <button onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();">Voeg samen</button><br />
    <br />
    <form id="form" action="feedgen.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <textarea name="values[]"></textarea>
        <textarea name="values[]"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
```

Any suggestions on how to create this in PHP?

Comment: Please explain it clearly,what you have tried so far.

Comment: I just can't think of a logical way to loop over these values to get the required result.

Comment: I've just expanded the example of output with an example of three lists.